# typescript can't resolve typing from graphql query that returns a union type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-query, graphql-codegen

I would like to understand what is going on here, and since i'm not very experienced with typescript, any help would be greatly appreciated !

I've got a resolver to return one cost from database :

```js
  @Query(() => FixedOrVariableCost, { name: 'oneCost' })
  async getOneCost(
    @Args('id', { type: () => String }) id: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId
  ) {
    return this.costsService.getOneCost(id);
  }
```

Its return type FixedOrVariableCost is a union type :

```js
const FixedOrVariableCost = createUnionType({
  name: 'FixedOrVariableCost',
  types: () => [FixedCost, VariableCost] as const,
});
```

Basically in my model, a cost is a fixed or a variable one. Cost is an abstract interface in my graphql layer.

Generated schema :

```
union FixedOrVariableCost = FixedCost | VariableCost

oneCost(id: String!): FixedOrVariableCost!
```

Here is the query i'm using :

```js
const useGetOneCost = (id: string) =>
  useQuery(['getOneCost', id], async () => {
    return (
      graphQLClient.request(
        gql`
          query GetOneCost($id: String!) {
            oneCost(id: $id) {
              ... on Cost {
                _id
                kind
                code
                label
                title
                content
                costType {
                  _id
                  code
                  label
                }
                costMargin {
                  _id
                  code
                  label
                }
                createdAt
                createdBy {
                  _id
                }
                updatedAt
                updatedBy {
                  _id
                }
                status {
                  _id
                  code
                  label
                  color
                }
              }
              ... on FixedCost {
                fixedCostValue {
                  amount
                  currency {
                    _id
                    code
                    label
                    symbol
                  }
                }
              }
              ... on VariableCost {
                variableCostValue
              }
            }
          }
        `,
        { id }
      ),
      {
        enabled: !!id,
      }
    );
  });
```

The typing generated by graphql codegen is the following :

```js
export type GetOneCostQuery = {
  __typename?: 'Query';
  oneCost:
    | {
        __typename?: 'FixedCost';
        _id: string;
        kind: CostKind;
        code: string;
        label: string;
        title?: string | null;
        content?: string | null;
        createdAt: any;
        updatedAt: any;
        costType: {
          __typename?: 'CostType';
          _id: string;
          code: string;
          label: string;
        };
        costMargin: {
          __typename?: 'CostMargin';
          _id: string;
          code: string;
          label: string;
        };
        createdBy: { __typename?: 'User'; _id: string };
        updatedBy: { __typename?: 'User'; _id: string };
        status: {
          __typename?: 'GenericStatus';
          _id: string;
          code: string;
          label: string;
          color: string;
        };
        fixedCostValue: {
          __typename?: 'FixedCostValue';
          amount: number;
          currency: {
            __typename?: 'Currency';
            _id: string;
            code: string;
            label: string;
            symbol: string;
          };
        };
      }
    | {
        __typename?: 'VariableCost';
        _id: string;
        kind: CostKind;
        code: string;
        label: string;
        title?: string | null;
        content?: string | null;
        createdAt: any;
        updatedAt: any;
        variableCostValue: number;
        costType: {
          __typename?: 'CostType';
          _id: string;
          code: string;
          label: string;
        };
        costMargin: {
          __typename?: 'CostMargin';
          _id: string;
          code: string;
          label: string;
        };
        createdBy: { __typename?: 'User'; _id: string };
        updatedBy: { __typename?: 'User'; _id: string };
        status: {
          __typename?: 'GenericStatus';
          _id: string;
          code: string;
          label: string;
          color: string;
        };
      };
};
```

very nice ! Typing generation works as expected

Now, one of my component receives a cost as a prop, so i'm picking `oneCost` inside `GetOneCostQuery` type

```js
type PropType<TObj, TProp extends keyof TObj> = TObj[TProp];

type OneCost = PropType<GetOneCostQuery, 'oneCost'>;

type Props = {
  cost: OneCost;
};

export const MyComponent = ({
  cost
}: Props) => {
  console.log(cost.fixedCostValue);
  return null;
}
```

ts error on ``fixedCostValue :

```
La propriété 'fixedCostValue' n'existe pas sur le type '{ __typename?: "FixedCost" | undefined; _id: string; kind: CostKind; code: string; label: string; title?: string | null | undefined; content?: string | null | undefined; createdAt: any; ... 6 more ...; fixedCostValue: { ...; }; } | { ...; }'.
  La propriété 'fixedCostValue' n'existe pas sur le type '{ __typename?: "VariableCost" | undefined; _id: string; kind: CostKind; code: string; label: string; title?: string | null | undefined; content?: string | null | undefined; createdAt: any; ... 6 more ...; status: { ...; }; }'.ts(2339)
```

roughly in english : "Property 'fixedCostValue' doesn't exist on type blablabla"

Shouldn't this value *maybe* available, if cost is a fixed one ? Why can't typescript recognize this value ? This confuses me ...

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `OneCost` is a union, meaning it is one of two objects - either `FixedCost` or `VariableCost`.
While the first contains an attribute named `fixedCostValue`, the second one doesn't, hence the error.

If you'll check if this attribute exists in the object, it'll pass. for example:

```
export const MyComponent = ({
  cost
}: Props) => {
  if ("fixedCostValue" in cost) {
    console.log(cost.fixedCostValue);
  };
  return null;
}
```